# Delphi 11 Alexandria: Version info is missing from EXE

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, fileversioninfo

(Original question: I added a `VERSIONINFO` resource to the project, but it is missing from the compiled executable. I did a text search both in ANSI and Unicode, but the pattern is not found. Of course, the "*Include version information in project*" checkbox is ticked. Is it a bug or something I missed?)

Edited:
I try to reproduce the problem step by step with an empty project, but I can't, because the compiled program will contain the required version info. The steps are:

– I created an empty VCL forms application project

- I repeated 2 steps below for all combinations of platforms and configurations:
  -- in Project options/Version info I added a key "foobar" with value "barfoo"
  -- I set Locale ID to $040$
- saved and compiled the project
- checked with Resource Hacker, the version info contains VALUE "FooBar", "BarFoo"

But then in the original problematic project, I see very similar version info settings: all platform/target combinations contain the specific key/value pair, locale ID's are set to $040$. So there are some magically wrong settings, perhaps in the .DPROJ file, that cause that the compiled exe won't contain the added key/value pair in the version info.

Edit2:
Sorry, the correct Locale ID is $040E (Hungarian). Both projects use the same toolchain. GExperts and a hacked version of DDevExtensions is installed. I tried to use ProjectMagician but later uninstalled. But those do not affect the problem. I use UPX, but the examined exe is unpacked. Later I re-imported the problematic project into XE11 as if it was a D7 project: I deleted all the project  files except the .DPR, reopened the project and added target platform Win64, version info values and all other project settings manually. After a succesful compile, the problem still persists. I think, the project has a hidden or erroneus reference to an invalid resource file. But I still can't find it.

Comment: It has never happened to me, so hard to say why it happens to you, especially as you did not show how and what you did. Perhaps you can edit your question and show that.

Comment: `VERSIONINFO` resources in an EXE binary are always in UTF-16 (where "Unicode" could mean any of the encodings). Inspect your EXE with f.e. [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I try to reproduce the problem step by step with an empty project,, but I can't. The steps are:

Comment: Yes, I did. I used the Edit button, wrote an approx. 10 line comment, and the rest of it had gone to the Moon. The steps are - .... I try to edit the original question. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: `$040$` can't be a correct value - do you mean `$0404`? And do your "empty" projects also use all plugins/tools that your "problem" project uses? I.e. madExcept or a packer? Those could alter the binary and accidentally/purposely remove certain resources.

Comment: Make sure you have your version info defined in all build configurations, not just in the base configuration for all platforms.

Comment: Maybe you have deleted or edited the `{$R *.res}` entry in your `.dpr` file? Check spelling!

Comment: I got it. This is a Delphi 11 BUG. It can be reproduced: create new VCL application, add new key/value to version info, compile. If the value is 1 character long, the entry is omitted from the version info resource. Add a second character to the value, recompile, then the entry will appear in the resource. Delphi XE2 is not buggy (at least this way), so the problem arised when I ported the program to ver 11.

Comment: Submit a bug report to Quality Portal.

Comment: Submitted: RSP-39712

Comment: Originally you said: *I added a VERSIONINFO resource to the project, but it is missing from the compiled executable.* With that I understood that the **whole** VERSIONINFO resource was missing. Now it seems you say that the VERSIONINFO resource is there but the `FooBar` key and value is missing if the value is a single character. I just wanted to point out the importance of being factually precise when asking questions. Anyway thanks for reporting to QP.